# Borel Sets which are not intervals

Tags: analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for an element of the Borel-sigma-algebra which is not an (open, closed, half-open,...) interval.

Can someone provide any example or an algorithm to construct them?

Answer (score 3):

How about the union of two disjoint intervals?

Any countable set also works.

Answer (score 3):

For a more funky example, look at the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Answer (score 0):

Also notice that since Borel Set contains every interval and since sigma algebra it is closed under countable intersection we have that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[x-\frac{1}{i},x+\frac{1}{i}\right]=\{x\}$$
Thus Borel Sigma Algebra contains every singleton